# Have two css elements together

Tags: html, css

I want to have two buble speech togethers and and with the some extra information.
Image below

[image]

This is my code for doing this:
I have a demo for this here: http://jsfiddle.net/pZh4w/

```
<style>
.bubble 
{
position: relative;
width: 525px;
height: 130px;
padding: 4px;
background: #FFFFFF;
-webkit-border-radius: 31px;
-moz-border-radius: 31px;
border-radius: 31px;
border: #46A5E4 solid 9px;
display:inline-block;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-right: 50px;
}

.test
{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 850px;
}
.test1
{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 850px;
}

.tes
{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 250px;
}
.tes1
{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 250px;
}
</style>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's simply not clear to me what you're trying to do.

Comment: Can we just build one speech bubble to show you the way?

Comment: Couldn't you just contain both within the same <div> element? But yeah, it's not clear what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: In the above image I have it. I want to have the two bubble speech together and below them I want to add extra information.

Comment: Here is an image of what exactly I am trying to achieve [link](http://screencast.com/t/ZOlnFH4YqqV)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something to get you started.

I would suggest the following HTML:

```
<div class="bubble">
    <p>First paragraph</p>
    <div class="caption">
         <h1>By PEDE</h1>
         <h2>From Belgrade,MT</h2>
         <h3>September 25,2013</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

and start with the following CSS:

```
.bubble-panel {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px dotted #CCCCCC;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;
}
.bubble {
    width: 525px;
    height: 130px;
    padding: 4px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 31px;
    -moz-border-radius: 31px;
    border-radius: 31px;
    border: #46A5E4 solid 9px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.caption {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 20em;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
.caption h1, .caption h2, .caption h3 {
    font-size: 1.00em;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;

}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/rcNN6/

The net result gives something like:

[image]

The speech bubble decoration (the little triangular bit that sticks out) can be built
by following the ideas presented at: http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/

The trick is to wrap the bubble and caption texts in a inline-block wrapper of fixed height.  These can then form a 2x2 grid if the screen is wide enough.

Comment: Hi Marc.
I have an image showing exactly what I am trying to achieve [link](http://screencast.com/t/ZOlnFH4YqqV)

Comment: How much text will go in the `.caption` block?

Comment: 20 characters per line, 3 lines 60 characters in total.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I update the code for the bubble decoration: http://jsfiddle.net/rcNN6/5/